# ng command not identifying angular workspace

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have a working angular workspace generated by nx. I am attempting to add angular material to the workspace with the following command:

```
ng add @angular/material
```

However I am getting the following error each time:

```
The add command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
Exception: ng exited with 1
```

Relevant dependencies are as follows:

```
        "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "11.0.0",
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1101.3",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~1.1.0",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~1.1.0",
        "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~1.1.0",
        "@angular/cli": "^11.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.1.2",
        "@angular/language-service": "^11.1.2",
        "@jscutlery/semver": "^1.3.1",
        "@ngneat/tailwind": "^6.0.3",
        "@nrwl/cli": "11.2.10",
        "@nrwl/cypress": "11.2.10",
        "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "11.2.10",
        "@nrwl/jest": "11.2.10",
        "@nrwl/linter": "11.2.10",
        "@nrwl/storybook": "^11.2.10",
        "@nrwl/tao": "11.2.10",
        "@nrwl/workspace": "11.2.10",


    "dependencies": {
        "@activejs/core": "0.2.3",
        "@angular-architects/ddd": "^1.1.0",
        "@angular-architects/module-federation": "^1.2.3",
        "@angular/animations": "^11.1.2",
        "@angular/cdk": "11.1.2",
        "@angular/common": "^11.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "^11.1.2",
        "@angular/core": "^11.1.2",
        "@angular/elements": "11.1.2",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "11.0.0-beta.33",
        "@angular/forms": "^11.1.2",
        "@angular/material": "11.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.1.2",
        "@angular/pwa": "0.1101.3",
        "@angular/router": "^11.1.2",
        "@angular/service-worker": "11.1.2",
```

I am using LinuxMint v20.x
Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you are running the command from correct project location

Comment: If you have a workspace.json instead of angular.json file in the root of the project: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67742047/1775703

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:** `npx nx g @angular/material:ng-add --project=my-project-name`, as stated here: [a solution for adding @angular/material to a Nx Workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66498407/add-angular-material-to-nx-workspace#answer-71275473).

---

For making use of ng commands the nrwl team have decide to wrap them (decorate them) under his own cli.
When facing a problem in your Nx Workspace related with libraries or the ng command, try these approaches and discover what works the better for your use case. E.g.:

- `nx generate @angular/material:ng-add --project=my-project-name`
- `yarn add @angular/material`
- `nx generate @nrwl/angular:component components/my-component --project=my-project-name` (Important: use the project flag) to generate a component in the components folder of the project.
- Use the raw ng CLI with: `FORCE_NG_UPDATE=true nx your-ng-command-goes-here`, where FORCE_NG_UPDATE is a variable set in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the error when trying to run the command in a directory where is not an angular project present. Make sure you navigate to inside the project folder, for example: ~/projects/new-angular-app/, then run the command

Comment: I am pretty sure I am in the correct directory. Many other commands do work. For instance I added navigation to the app using same.

Comment: Hmmm I'll try to investigate further but that is my only advice for now

Comment: I am using pnpm as package manager - not sure if this could be the cause. I am wondering if the command is looking for angular.json, while workspace.json is what is generated.

Comment: Ah I'm not familiar with pnpm. It could very well be that