# Add Angular Material to Nx Workspace

Tags: angular, angular-material, nrwl-nx

I'm wanting to add angular-material to my nx-workspace.

The angular material docs (https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) say I should run `ng add @angular/material`.

I've tried that in the root of my nx workspace, as well as in an application folder I want to add it to, as well as in a lib project folder I want to add it to. In all cases I get the message
`The add command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.`

The Angular Material docs used to include instructions on how to add dependencies manually, but I can't find that anymore. Does anyone know how to add it to projects in an Nx workspace these days?

Comment: I think you need to use `nx` as a replacement for `ng` in an nx workspace.

`yarn nx add @angular/material`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`npx nx g @angular/material:ng-add --project=my-project-name` is the command you need to run in your Nx Workspace.

Do not forget to include the project name or you will see errors.

Additionally, If you continue having errors try by answering `no` to the questions about `Set up global Angular Material typography styles` and `Set up browser animations for Angular Material`.

Disclaimer: Another member already answered correctly in the comments but I think a simple answer like this one should be pinned.

Comment: Before you can do this, you need to install @angular/material `npm install -D @angular/material`.

Comment: @fonzane Why -D? Isn't it a part of main dependencies?

Comment: you are right, this is not correct (anymore). I think you had to install it as a dev dependency in older versions (not sure).

Answer (score 23):

If you created the an empty workspace you don't have angular.json, you will have a workspace.json, which is almost identical I think.

Assuming that you have already generated an agular app:

1. Install the angular material lib: `yarn add @angular/material`
2. To see the avaible commands from the nx console: `nx list @angular/material`
   [image]
3. To add angular material to the default project: `nx generate @angular/material:ng-add`
   [image]

PS. Probably it will thrown an error on nx not found/installed. `yarn add -g @nrwl/cli`. I think is possible to add angular material to another project, didn't try that yet

https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/3779#issuecomment-751136586

Comment: I did what you advice and get the error `Bootstrap call not found` during the `nx generate @angular/material:ng-add`.

Comment: I figured it out, I needed to specify the project: `nx generate @angular/material:ng-add --project=my-project`

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add angular material icon support to Nx ?

Comment: how to handle when I run command : nx generate @angular/material:ng-add and got peer dependencies conflict ? --force flag & --legacy-peer-deps seem not works?

Answer (score 17):

```
npm install @angular/material && npx nx g @angular/material:ng-add
```

Then follow the same as material docs

Answer (score 8):

`npm i @angular/material && npx nx g @angular/material:ng-add --project=my-project-name`

That should do it.

Answer (score 5):

To find out Nx angular material plugin

> nx list @angular/material

To install the plugin in dev dependencies

> npm install -D @angular/material

Answer (score 1):

First you install Angular material using **npm**

```
npm install @angular/material --save
```

Then you run the following command:

```
npx nx g @angular/material:ng-add --project=your-project-name
```

if you don't do first step you'll get the following error:

```
 >  NX   Unable to resolve @angular/material:ng-add.

   Cannot find module '@angular/material/package.json'
   Require stack:
   - /workspaces/myproject/node_modules/nx/src/utils/package-json.js
   - /workspaces/myproject//node_modules/nx/src/utils/package-manager.js
   - /workspaces/myproject//node_modules/nx/bin/init-local.js
   - /workspaces/myproject//node_modules/nx/bin/nx.js
   Pass --verbose to see the stacktrace.
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I created a new Angular project (without Nx) and ran the `ng add @angular/material` command there, then took a look at the diff that resulted, and applied those changes in the Nx workspace and that seems to work fine. Just wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Yarn will cause build errors when using theming. I was running my build with yarn. It will complain about the @use '~@angular/material' as mat; being in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
yarn add -W @angular/material && yarn nx g @angular/material:ng-add
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

While running the command

`npm install @angular/material && npx nx g @angular/material:ng-add  --project=<project_name>` I faced the below issue

```
SchematicsException [Error]: Bootstrap call not found
    at findBootstrapModulePath (/Users/san/project/Sample/fetebird-ui/node_modules/@schematics/angular/utility/ng-ast-utils.js:67:15)
    at getAppModulePath (/Users/san/project/Sample/fetebird-ui/node_modules/@schematics/angular/utility/ng-ast-utils.js:85:32)
    at addAnimationsToNonStandaloneApp (/Users/san/project/Sample/fetebird-ui/node_modules/@angular/material/schematics/ng-add/setup-project.js:94:61)
    at /Users/san/project/Sample/fetebird-ui/node_modules/@angular/material/schematics/ng-add/setup-project.js:58:13
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async callRuleAsync (/Users/san/project/Sample/fetebird-ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/rules/call.js:77:18)

 >  NX   Bootstrap call not found
```

To resolve the issue, change the below configuration in each application `project.json`

```
"targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
```

Also, need to change the `option` main to `bootstrap` instead of `main`

```
 "options": {
        "main": "apps/host/src/bootstrap.ts",
```

Reference - https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/7621

Once done with the angular material installation, revert the changes