# I want to make nx project with angular universal ang nestjs server rendering

Tags: angular, nestjs, angular-universal, nomachine-nx

when i run this

```
nx generate  @nxarch/ng-nest:init --ssrApp=eulembro-client --serverApp=eulembro-server
```

i get this error

```
   nx Bootstrap call not found
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I have the same problem

Comment: No, I haven't solve

Comment: @MhmdAl-Rshedy this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/76240963/3277581